# C# on windows ce 6.0 OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce, out-of-memory

I have a list of items I want to load in my device, when I tried to load them all into memory my application throw me a `OutOfMemoryException`.
My application load `500,000 items`, and I need to access them the fastest way possible (The end users do not want to wait 30 sec after scanning an item to see if it exist in the list).
I am using `compact framework 3.5 I` have no access to any wireless and  the file exist as a binary file in the device.

I need something like this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robtiffany/archive/2009/04/09/memmaker-for-the-net-compact-framework.aspx but it seems to not working the same way for CE 6.0.

Answer (score 3):

To manage that much data on a mobile device you should be using a compact/lite db like [SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx), [SQLite](http://sqlite-wince.sourceforge.net/) or [Firebird Embedded](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html).

You can manage the data yourself but you will find that you're reinventing the wheel. Instead of tweaking with the memory, as the article suggests, make use of SQL Server Compact's indexing and other built-in memory management. Look-ups like the one you describe are trivial for such engines.

Answer (score 2):

Your "fast as possible" is funny.  You have to sort out OOM first.

Your users don't want to deal with 500K of anything all at once.

Follow Google's example: Your web searches return millions of hits, but they send back 25 at a time, sorted by priority.  That's what you should do, too.

Better to use a database like SQLite3 and mimic Google.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a raw binary file, then I'd open it as a [memory-mapped file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138290/Programming-Memory-Mapped-Files-with-the-NET-Frame).  If you're lucky and the "items" are fixed-width and sorted by some value, binary searches would be extremely fast and mapping it will probably take only 64k of RAM.

Comment: memory mapped files work fine in CE - you just have to define the P/Invokes.  I've got a full CF implementation, but it's too big to post in a SO response.